# Add double quotes to string in python

Tags: python, string

If my input text is

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

and I want my output text to be: (with the double quotes)

```
"a b c d e f g"
```

Where do I go after this step:

```
" ".join([a.strip() for a in b.split("\n") if a])
```

Comment: Have you tried `'"' + your_current_string + '"'`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have successfully constructed a string without the quotes. So you need to add the double quotes. There are a few different ways to do this in Python:

```py
>>> my_str = " ".join([a.strip() for a in b.split("\n") if a])
>>> print '"' + my_str + '"'     # Use single quotes to surround the double quotes
"a b c d e f g"
>>> print "\"" + my_str + "\""   # Escape the double quotes
"a b c d e f g"
>>> print '"%s"' % my_str        # Use old-style string formatting
"a b c d e f g"
>>> print '"{}"'.format(my_str)  # Use the newer format method
"a b c d e f g"
```

Or in Python 3.6+:

```py
>>> print(f'"{my_str}"')         # Use an f-string
"a b c d e f g"
```

Any of these options are valid and idiomatic Python. I might go with the first option myself, or the last in Python 3, simply because they're the shortest and clearest.

Answer (score 3):

```
'"%s"' % " ".join([a.strip() for a in s.split("\n") if a])
```