# ex1.py Won't print at line 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

I had an exercise about how to print. I tried to print this code:

```
print "Hello World!."
print "Hello Again."
print "I like typing this."
print "this is fun."
print "Yay, Printing."
print "I would much rather you 'not'."
print "I "Said" do not touch this."
```

But when I try run it on the terminal it gives me an error:

```
  File "ex1.py", line 7
print "I "Said" do not touch this."
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You can't put double quotes in double quotes without escaping - `Said` is *outside of the string*.

Comment: I see so how to print it with double quotes any solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add double quotes to string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38535707/add-double-quotes-to-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print actual quote marks, you need to either...

Escape them with backslashes:

```
print "I \"Said\" do not touch this."
```

Or enclose the entire string in the other kind of quote mark (single vs. double):

```
print 'I "Said" do not touch this.'
```